# The logical structure of the network based on the analysis of incoming packets

Tags: networking, ip, ttl

I need to determine whether the two belong to the ip-address subnet, knowing ttl.

For example, I received 200 packets from each of two ip-addresses. For each of these I have kept the maximum and minimum values ​​of ttl.

x.x.x.10   with minimum ttl=68 maximum ttl=69  
x.x.x.110  with minimum ttl=69 maximum ttl=70

Is it possible on the basis of these data to determine whether owned by a single ip-address subnet or not? Thanks.

Comment: Who is sending these packets, and how? What does TTL have to do with it? Ssurely the source address is what you should be looking at?

Comment: I want to write a program that is based on the TTL concludes that if the two  ip-address belong to a single subnet or not. If the packets pass through the same number of routers, it is considered that they belong to the same subnet. The problem is that I do not know what to do if the TTL values are not identical and differ by 1 such as in the example